# How to fix Render Error createElement() in JSX in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render my `<App />` component and I keep getting `TypeError: cannot read property createElement of undefined` in the `<Home />`, `<Navbar />` and `<Login />` components, when I try to compile the project. All errors indicate Line 9 in `Index.js` Here is what it contains:

`Login.js` Line 3

```
import { React } from "react";

const Login = () => (
  <div>
    ...
```

`Home.js` Line 4

```
import { React } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => (
  <div className="jumbotron">
 ...
```

`Navbar.js` Line 6

```
import { React } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

function Navbar() {
  const activeStyle = { color: "#F15B2A" };
  return (
    <nav>
    ...
```

I am interested in understanding why I keep getting errors at the component declaration in these components or is it something related to the return and render methods and how I call them?

Comment: I updated my answer with some further explanation. It's related to the fact that you're rendering JSX in your components. Therefore, React needs to be default imported like this: ```import React from "react"```

Comment: It worked. I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're rendering JSX in your component declaration files, you need to import `React` (default import) so that the JSX is recognized.

Change the following lines in all your files from:

```js
import { React } from 'react'
```

to import React like this: (without brackets).

```js
import React from 'react'
```

Comment: This leads to a similar error with my ```<Navbar />``` component; it clears for this component when I add the brackets. Apparently when exporting any module other than React, the brackets must be added.

Comment: What's the error you're getting with your navbar component? Please share the full project in Codesandbox so that the community can help you.

Comment: Create a sandbox on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/) and put your project's code then share the link

Comment: It doesn't have to do with imports from React specifically, its the difference between a default and named export/import. `React` is the default import, but it also has named imports available like `Component`. Its up to the package (or you if you write the components) to determine how things are exported. You are then responsible to import them matching the export type.

Comment: For example: `export default MyComponent` => `import MyComponent from 'package'`. Or `export const MyComponent` => `import { MyComponent } from 'package'`. The import type is usually included in the documentation or examples for packages.